# React Site Builds and Deploys Successfully, but shows up as a blank white page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, hosting

So I'm new to web dev and I've been building a React site just to try it out. It worked great locally, and so then I followed a tutorial to get it hosted on github. The build and deploy process goes smoothly, nothing seems wrong. Then I try to open the site and it's just a blank white page and inspect is telling me.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Here is the full [repo](https://joonhyoo.github.io/test-site/)

I tried pushing it to a fresh github repo, on the off chance something just went wrong within git somehow. Other than that, I haven't tried too much and have been really stuck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using a GitHub workflow that's not actually building your content. When looking into your Actions (the feature of GH that can build your site for you) I found that Jekyll (a static site generator) is used for rendering. It only finds your assets and the `index.html` file, which is what you're seeing in the browser. In this case, that's wrong since you want to use Vite and not Jekyll to build the site. Vite has an article on deploying your static site to GH Pages [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages).

Comment: Also, you provided a link to the GitHub page but not the repository - for quicker responses both would be great in the future. Cheers!

Comment: oh woops I totally thought I had sent in my repo

Answer (score 0):

As I can notice, you have declared `src/main.tsx` file as the main file that deals with `root node` of your application.

In the `createRoot()` where you are fetching `document.getElementById("root")` , there is unexpected `!` that should not be there.

the `createRoot()` is expected to be written like this:-

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: the ! is a typescript not null assertion, so that wouldn't be the problem here, but thanks for the help anyway